# Spring Consul - disable for unit tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, service-discovery

## Updated

My class listed below (`ServiceDiscoveryConfiguration`) is never being utilized.  Even if I remove the `@EnableDiscoveryClient` to attempt to completely avoid the setup, it still attempts to connect to Consul.

The only thing that worked for me was removing the Consul Maven depdency completely:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

What can I do to prevent Consul for running for unit tests if not through the profile and annotation setup?

## Original

I have an application using Spring Consul.
I have a class set up to enable discovery like this:

```
@Profile ("!" + Profiles.UNIT_TEST)
@Configuration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ServiceDiscoveryConfiguration {
}
```

This **should** be disabling the Consul portion, if I am not mistaken.  The base test class (it's an `abstract` shared between all of my unit tests) is setup up with the following annotations.  This is where I *think* the problem is.

```
@SpringBootTest (classes = Service.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners (...)
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles (Profiles.UNIT_TEST)
@Test (...)
public abstract class AbstractBootTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
  // ...
}
```

When I execute my tests I get:

> Caused by: com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

This leads me to believe that the profile activation is not working or my syntax using the `!` operator on the `@Profile` specification is not doing what I thought it was supposed to be doing.  The root execution class itself has basic annotations including a `@ComponentScan` annotation that I know has the appropriate packages being scanned.

Assistance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have `bootstrap.properties` file in your project, you should create `bootstrap.properties` file under `test/resources`:

```
spring.application.name=<service-name>
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=false
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false
```

This will disable consul integration in tests

Comment: AH!  That's an even better idea!

Answer (score 5):

You can disable via

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false"})
```

Answer (score 3):

Add below property in your application.properties file under test/resources

```
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false
```

This will disable consul integration while testing your application

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you have spring-consul in the classpath it will try to auto-configure it anyway

Comment: Any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

The profile annotation is correct

```
@Profile ("!" + Profiles.UNIT_TEST)
```

the profile activation looks ok, also

```
@ActiveProfiles (Profiles.UNIT_TEST)
```

You wrote you are using ComponentScan, that is important, because @Profile annotation on a bean is ignored, if the bean is instantiated by a @Bean annotated method. May be you check again, to see, this does not happen ?

To narrow down the problem you can try :

set a breakpoint in the constructor of ServiceDiscoveryConfiguration, to see if it is instantiated or not

remove @EnableDiscoveryClient to see if this is really the cause of your problems

Comment: I don't believe this is profile-related.  I am updating my question as I had to remove the Maven dependencies.

Comment: So after debugging, the class is never getting hit at all.  It's like it's ignoring that particular configuration option.